# nginx filtering based on JSON body

Tags: nginx

I have a Java API server sitting behind an nginx server. The nginx server provides HTTPS, rate limiting, logging, analytics etc.

There is a particular HTTP endpoint `/my-file-upload/{:file-id}` which takes up JSON body of type:

```
{
  FileName: <string>,
  Content: <base 64 encoded string>,
}
```

that needs to be handled by this combination of servers.

The Java server handles the actual file content processing. However, I want to have a whitelist of various file extensions (not necessarily file magic from the body) that would be allowed to pass from the nginx server to the Java server.

For example, I want to allow only PDFs (.pdf) and .txt file requests to be allowed, by filtering on the `FileName` field of the request body JSON. So far, I have used nginx filtering based on the `location` for filtering on the url. However, here I want to filter based on the request body, is there a standard way of achieving this in nginx using the configuration file, or do I need to write any plugins or is there any standard plugin to achieve this ?

Comment: If you are using JSON for file transfer then doesn't that you have to wait for the tranfer of the whole client request before you can parse it anyway? How are the clients initiating the upload? XMLHttpRequest/ajax/fetch from a browser or something else?

Comment: YEs, we receive the full file from the client. The clients use either a XMLHTTPRequest from the browser or a mobile (android/iOS) http client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options, depending on how "properly" you want to do it.

The real rough and dirty way is on the client side add some code to grab the file extension then modify your XMLHttpRequest code with `XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader()` to add an it to additional header field to the request with the file type. For example `X-Filetype: pdf`

Then inside your Nginx upload location you reject any uploads with the wrong value in this header:

```
if ($http_x_filetype !~ (pdf|txt)) {
    return 415;
}
```

Nginx now returns `415 Unsupported Media Type` for other uploads.

Pros: It's easy
Cons: It's easy to get around, using an `if` condition within a location is Nginx sacrilege

At the other end of the scale you implement the FileReader API in your javascript, attach an event listener to your file upload form then when a client selects a file use the FileReader to slice the first few bytes into an Array Buffer and add these to the headers as in previous example.

In Nginx you need the `auth_request` module, which is not built as default with a standard Nginx install but several of the package manager distributions have it. You can check by running:

```
nginx -V 2>&1 | grep -qF -- --with-http_auth_request_module && echo ":)" || echo ":("
```

Within your upload location block you set an internal location for Nginx to call on each request. The response code from this subrequest determines whether or not Nginx allows client access.

```
location /my-file-upload {
    auth_request /filecheck;
    ........
}

location /filecheck {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/my-auth-script.php; #or whatever
    proxy_set_header X-Filehex $http_x_filehex;
    ....
}
```

Pass whatever info you need to your internal script which does your file type validation and client identification. MD5 hash of expected file, expected filesize, whatever might be useful to ensure if you allow the upload then the file you get is the file you expect to get.

If your script is happy it returns 200, if not it returns 403. Nginx then proxies to your upload server if it gets a 200 response, and denies the request if it gets 403